# tmux prevents bash from seeing ctrl commands

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, tmux

in my `.bashrc`, I have

```
bind -r '\C-s'
stty -ixon
#bind C-s to go backword (puns) - moves cursor to previous [:space:] on cmd line
set -o ignoreeof
bind '"\C-s": shell-backward-word'
#bind C-d to go forword
bind '"\C-d": shell-forward-word'
```

These work on OSX High Sierra in iTerm2. However, if I'm in a tmux session (2.7) on the same, they do not work.

My `.tmux.conf` doesn't contain any instances of `C-s` or `C-d`, my prefix is `C-a` which shouldn't interfere. The only thing that references any of that is `set-environment -g 'IGNOREEOF' 2` which should just tell tmux to ignore `C-d`.

I have no idea what is going wrong, or how to debug this issue. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check your final bindings with `tmux list-keys`. check with `stty -a` that you still have `-ixon`. Run something like `cat -vet` and type the control chars to see what gets through.

Comment: `cat -vet` shows `^S` for `C-d` and `C-s` both. `stty -a` shows both `-ixon` and `-ixoff` (which is not the most intuitive until I looked it up). `list-keys` shows only a handful of root commands, none of which should overlap.

Comment: This shows the control-s is being passed by tmux to the program (cat). Perhaps your shell has lost the binding? List them with `bash -p`

Comment: I don't think that's what `bash -p` does. From `bash -c "help set"` I don't see any bash argument that would list all bindings (it also says that `-p` has to do with setting effective uid/gid to the real uid/gid). I am confused, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `bind -p`.

Comment: `bind -p | grep C-s` returns `"\C-s": shell-backward-word`

Comment: @meuh, hey, it just started working. ... I have no idea why. I've been editing my bashrc in the interim but nothing that should have interefered with this. I haven't changed my tmux or iterm configs at all. I guess I'm good with this. Thanks for your help.